# Android, how to implement a *real* multi select spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, multi-select

Is there a simple way in Android to let a spinner accept multiple selections?

I can't believe I have to implement a class myself for such a basic behaviour... :-(

*** UPDATE ***

Ok, the solution is to go with ListViews, but, how do I make a ListView behave like a spinner, i.e., when not selected it should be closed, showing only the default or selected item, plus a down arrow to allow user to open the ListView...

Should I implement the "spinner" behaviour from scratch?

*** UPDATE UPDATE ***

Should I better try to skin a Button as Spinner to create a custom multiselect spinner, or it's better to extend Spinner?

Comment: Have you tried a MultiSpinner?

Something like this...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015686/android-spinner-with-multiple-choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spinner is for single selection only. You can use a ListView to have multiple selection.

Comment: Ok, but how do I let it behave like a spinner, i.e: start closed, with only the default item viewable, and a down arrow to open the list?

Comment: I accept this question - even if quite lean and rawboned - because I no other answer arrived.