# how to change the dropdown height in spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-spinner

i tried a lot to change the dropdown item height  of spinner.. but i couldn't get a good solution.. plz help me guys..

here is a code
loginactivityview.xml

```
       <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spinnerFacility"
         android:layout_width="400dip"
         android:layout_height="50dip"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lpassword"
         android:layout_below="@+id/lpassword"
         android:layout_marginTop="32dip"            
         android:background="@drawable/location" 
         android:paddingLeft="10dip"               
         android:dropDownWidth="@style/dropDown"  
         android:minHeight="40dip"     
         android:typeface="monospace" />
```

loginrowspinner.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewRowFacility"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:text="Facility"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20dip" >
</TextView>
```

[image]

how to change the height of drop down any idea..

Comment: Check following URL for the exact solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878260/how-to-re-size-the-height-of-the-items-in-spinner-with-multiple-choice

Comment: you should mark John's post as answer.

Answer (score 62):

Just add this to your adapter.

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: ...so clever solution :)

Comment: simple_spinner_dropdown_item is the default android layout and should not be edited. Btw. changing anything inside has no effect for my spinners. Better to add android:minHeight="80dp" to your Spinner section in layout xml

Comment: if you use this, you cant edit your layout...  and  if you give your layout id it also not work... this not solve error

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it can help..

```
ArrayAdapter<String> yourSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.spinner_item, yourItem) {

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView,
                    parent);

            convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = convertView.getLayoutParams();
            p.height = 100; // set the height
            convertView.setLayoutParams(p);

            return convertView;
        }
    };
```

Comment: A perfect solution, effects only the drop down elements and not the text view of the selected item.

Answer (score 7):

In loginrowspinner.xml, add `android:minHeight="48dp"` to `TextView` element.

```
 <TextView 
     ...
     android:id="@+id/textViewRowFacility"
     android:minHeight="48dp" />
```

Comment: Where that TextView comes from in Spinner?

Comment: this is not work when there two kind layout type

Answer (score 4):

Create your own textview in layout folder like this which will be populated in dropdown popup

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:textAlignment="inherit" />
```

Note I have provided

```
android:layout_height="60dp"
```

and

```
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
```

and use this for your spinner, like this

```
Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sosMode);
String[] items = new String[]{"Date", "Travelling alone"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_dropdown_list, items);
dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this works for me :)

Comment: `layout_height` was what I was looking for to change the height of the spinner.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try using dps.

```
@Override   
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    TextView textview = (TextView)inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null);

    textview.setText(alOpcion.get(position).getOpcionName());

    DisplayMetrics metrics = parent.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = 40f;
    float fpixels = metrics.density * dp;
    int pixels = (int) (fpixels + 0.5f);

    textview.setHeight(pixels);

    return textview;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like `android:layout_height="30dp"` instead of `fill_parent` for either of those  elements in loginrowspinner.xml?

Comment: s boss it will change the height of spinner it is no use.. i want dropdown height

Answer (score 0):

add this in your adapter : convertView.setMinimumHeight(60); which works for me.

Answer (score 0):

//This might also help:

```
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dataForAdapter) {


        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            v.setMinimumHeight((int) (40*cx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(222, 222, 222));


            return v;
        }

    };
```

Comment: Could you please explain '`40*cx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density`' ?

Comment: @backslashN, when writing Java code for Android, you can't use dp units and have to specify in pixels instead (unlike XML, which accepts dp also). If you set 40px for all cases, the height will still look small on screens with a lot of pixels. That's why we use this code to take the current device density into account

Answer (score 0):

Override method in ArrayAdapter class

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    view.getLayoutParams().height = 50;
    return view;
}
```

Comment: It crash java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView"

Answer (score 0):

Got stuck in same problem.Found following solution to be working for me:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        setSpinnerDropDownHeight()
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            mBinding?.included?.spinn?.getViewTreeObserver()?.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                    mBinding?.included?.spinn?.dropDownVerticalOffset = mBinding?.included?.spinn?.getDropDownVerticalOffset()!! + mBinding?.included?.spinn?.getHeight()!!
                    mBinding?.included?.spinn?.viewTreeObserver!!.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                }
            })

            mBinding?.included?.spinn?.dropDownVerticalOffset = 10
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps someone!!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As people say, best way is to add

```
    android:minHeight="48dp"
```

to .xml. But if you want to do it programatically use:

```
    mspinner.setMinimumHeight(48);
```

being mspinner the name of your spinner and 48 the new height of the option.