# Set height of drop down of spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to set Spinner drop down height.

My code for spinner is:

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/txt_filter_state"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:entries="@array/items_order_State"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:dropDownWidth="150dp"
        android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="150dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="State"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
```

I can set drop down width but not height,
Please help is there any property to set spinner drop down height.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `your_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`

Comment: possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870285/how-to-change-the-dropdown-height-in-spinner