# override default android attr styles

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-styles, android-attributes

This is a very basic question

I'm trying to create a spinner in my android layout. Then i found a website teaching how to create an `ArrayAdapter` for that spinner

```
 ArrayAdapter<Giveaway.GiveawayCategory> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Giveaway.GiveawayCategory>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new ArrayList<Giveaway.GiveawayCategory>(20));
        dataAdapter.add(ImportGiveawayActivity.selectCategory);

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        this.spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

it works very fine but there is a giant margin between the items...

So i looked into `simple_spinner_dropdown_item` and found:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

probably the `height` is not good, or the `style` sets a huge margin, i tried to find those files but i couldn't

How can i override these values in my style.xml

this is what i want to change
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to re size the Height of the Items in Spinner with multiple choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878260/how-to-re-size-the-height-of-the-items-in-spinner-with-multiple-choice)

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela, the idea is similar but the solution is not what i want... there must be an simplier way to override basic android styles... if the solution was to recreate my own layout and etc i would never ask a question here