# How to create a multi selection spinner with checkbox in android

Tags: android, sql, checkbox, spinner

I just wanna ask how can I create a multi selection spinner in android and the data that will be populated to is from the database. I saw this example here in SO [Android Spinner with multiple choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015686/android-spinner-with-multiple-choice) and tried to use it but I don't know what to do next.   This is my spinner and adapter and I want to make it in multiselect spinner. Help me please...

```
spn_CustomerSegment = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spn_CustomerSegment);
    List<String> ConsumerSeg = databaseHandler.setItemOnConsumerSeg();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(IreportMain.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ConsumerSeg);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spn_CustomerSegment.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Spinner with multiple choice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015686/android-spinner-with-multiple-choice)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47284385/1140304

Answer (score 0):

I know its not direct answer but you can try using a acrollView (vertical or horizontal) and populate it with checkboxes.
it can give you a nice effect end no extra coding is needed