# Multi selection spinner in android without AlertDialog

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-listview, spinner, android-spinner

i want the same as this link  https://www.gorecess.com/ first spinner . multi selection spinner in android with checkbox .Show the spinner in dropdown. anyone know answer...

Comment: You can use custom layout.

Comment: u know any link just refer me

Answer (score 8):

[image: MultiSelectionSpinner]

```
            <com.extra.MultiSelectionSpinner
                android:id="@+id/input1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp" />

       MultiSelectionSpinner spinner=(MultiSelectionSpinner)findViewById(R.id.input1);

       List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
          list.add("List1");
          list.add("List2");
          spinner.setItems(list);
```

Comment: Thanks, how to set placeholder?

Comment: Will you please tell me how to set place holder?

Answer (score 8):

**multi select spinner :**

> 1- create a spinner in your own xml ,like this

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
```

> 2-create a custom dapter for spinner like this :

```
public class AdapterTagSpinnerItem extends ArrayAdapter<TagListSimpleSearch>
{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<TagListSimpleSearch> listState;
    public Spinner mySpinner = null;

    public AdapterTagSpinnerItem(Context context, int resource, List<TagListSimpleSearch> objects, Spinner mySpinner)
    {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.listState = objects;
        this.mySpinner = mySpinner;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        String text = "";
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, null, false);
            holder.mTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSpinnerItem);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        /**
         * check position , if position is zero we put space on top of list of spinner
         */
        if ((position == 0))
            text = oneSpace;
        /**
         * check position , if position is one we put cross mark before text to show that position used to be for clear all selected items on spinner
         */
        else if ((position == 1))
            text = "  " + String.valueOf((char) crossMarkAroundBox) + " " + listState.get(position).getTagText();
        /**
         * check position , if position is two we put check mark before text to show that position used to be for select all items on spinner
         */         
        else if ((position == 2))
            text = "  " + String.valueOf((char) tikMarkAroundBox) + " " + listState.get(position).getTagText();
        /**
         * check position , if position is bigger than two we have to check that position is selected before or not and put check mark or dash before text 
         */         
        else
        {
            if (listState.get(position).isSelected())
            {
                text = "  " + String.valueOf((char) tikMark) + " " + listState.get(position).getTagText();
            }
            else
            {
                text = "  " + String.valueOf(dash) + " " + listState.get(position).getTagText();
            }
        }
        holder.mTextView.setText(text);
        holder.mTextView.setTag(position);
        holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                /**
                 * if you want open spinner after click on text for first time we have to open spinner programmatically 
                 */
                mySpinner.performClick();
                int getPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
                listState.get(getPosition).setSelected(!listState.get(getPosition).isSelected());
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                /**
                 * if clicked position is one 
                 * that means you want clear all select item in list 
                 */             
                if (getPosition == 1)
                {
                    clearList();
                }
                /**
                 * if clicked position is two 
                 * that means you want select all item in list 
                 */
                else if (getPosition == 2)
                {
                    fillList();
                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }


    /**
     * clear all items in list
     */
    public void clearList()
    {
        for (TagListSimpleSearch items : listState)
        {
            items.setSelected(false);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * select all items in list
     */
    public void fillList()
    {
        for (TagListSimpleSearch items : listState)
        {
            items.setSelected(true);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * view holder
     */
    private class ViewHolder
    {
        private TextView mTextView;
    }
}
```

> 3- now you have to create object for adapter

```
public class TagListSimpleSearch {

    private String TagId;
    private String TagText;
    private boolean selected;

    public String getTagId() {
        return TagId;
    }

    public void setTagId(String TagId) {
        this.TagId = TagId;
    }

    public String getTagText() {
        return TagText;
    }

    public void setTagText(String tagText) {
        TagText = tagText;
    }

    public boolean isSelected()
    {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected)
    {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

> 4-fill spinner adapter in your activity

```
public static String oneSpace =" ";
public static int tikMark =0X2714;
public static int crossMark =0X2715;
public static int tikMarkAroundBox =0X2611;
public static int crossMarkAroundBox =0X274E;
public static String dash ="-";
private Spinner mySpinner;

mySpinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
List<TagListSimpleSearch> tagsNames = new ArrayList<>();
TagListSimpleSearch tagSpecific=new TagListSimpleSearch();
tagSpecific.setTagId("0");
tagSpecific.setTagText(oneSpace);
tagsNames.add(tagSpecific);

tagSpecific=new TagListSimpleSearch();
tagSpecific.setTagId("1");
tagSpecific.setTagText("select All Items");
tagsNames.add(tagSpecific);

tagSpecific=new TagListSimpleSearch();
tagSpecific.setTagId("2");
tagSpecific.setTagText("remove All Items");
tagsNames.add(tagSpecific);

tagSpecific=new TagListSimpleSearch();
tagSpecific.setTagId("0");
tagSpecific.setTagText("Item 0");
tagsNames.add(tagSpecific);

tagSpecific=new TagListSimpleSearch();
tagSpecific.setTagId("1");
tagSpecific.setTagText("Item 1");
tagsNames.add(tagSpecific);

tagSpecific=new TagListSimpleSearch();
tagSpecific.setTagId("2");
tagSpecific.setTagText("Item 2");
tagsNames.add(tagSpecific);

tagSpecific=new TagListSimpleSearch();
tagSpecific.setTagId("3");
tagSpecific.setTagText("Item 3");
tagsNames.add(tagSpecific);

final AdapterTagSpinnerItem adapterTagSpinnerItem = new AdapterTagSpinnerItem(this, 0, tagsNames,mySpinner);
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapterTagSpinnerItem);
```

Comment: Can you post yout spinner_item layout

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a multiple selection spinner in android using AlertDialog

check the following code

```
 public void classesSelect(){


    regclassvalue.setText("");


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);


    builder.setTitle("Select Services");

    final int array[] = new int[serarray.length];

    check = new boolean[serarray.length];

    for (int k = 0; k < serarray.length; k++) {

        check[k] = false;

    }

    final List<String> classlist = Arrays.asList(serarray);

    final List<Integer> classidlist = Arrays.asList(classidarray);
```

// this is the main part here we set the multichoice listener using serarray and check

```
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(serarray, check, new                   DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

            check[which] = isChecked;

        }

    });

    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            regclassvalue.setText("");

            classids = "";

            int io = 0;

            for (int ii = 0; ii < check.length; ii++) {

                boolean checked = check[ii];

                if (checked) {

                    array[io] = ii;

                    io++;

                }

            }

            for (int k = 0; k < io; k++) {

                if (io == 1) {

                    classids = classids + classidlist.get(array[k]);

                    regclassvalue.setText(regclassvalue.getText() + classlist.get(array[k]));

                } else if (k == io - 1) {

                    classids = classids + classidlist.get(array[k]);

                    regclassvalue.setText(regclassvalue.getText() + classlist.get(array[k]));

                } else {

                    classids = classids + classidlist.get(array[k]) + ",";

                    regclassvalue.setText(regclassvalue.getText() + classlist.get(array[k]) + " ,");

                }

            }

            //Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,classids,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            dialog.cancel();



        }

    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    dialog.show();



}
```

for more info please click [here](https://programcoaster.blogspot.com/2019/10/multiselect-spinner-item-using.html)