# Multi Selection Spinner

Tags: android, dialog

I am using the code suggested at the following location: http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/09/spinner-with-multiple-selection-in.html to implement a multiselection spinner. Now the code does not define a onclick listener. I am trying to use it like this:

```
    String[] array = { "a", "b", "c"};
    MultiSelectionSpinner multiSpinner = (MultiSelectionSpinner)findViewById(R.id.multiSpinner);
    multiSpinner.setItems(array);

    //getting an error here
    multiSpinner.OnMultiChoiceClickListener(MultiSeekClickListener);



   }

   private OnMultiChoiceClickListener MultiSeekClickListener = new OnMultiChoiceClickListener( ...
```

Can someone please help me in updating the source code to include the listener or in case there is problem in my implementation, please point that out.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `... does not define a onclick listener`? You want to know when an item in the spinner is clicked?

Comment: yes, when an item is clicked OnMultiChoiceClickListener should read that item. right now if you go through the link I have provided, thw class implements OnMultiChoiceClickListener and inside there is a onClick code. I want to implement .. 
'private OnMultiChoiceClickListener multilistener = new OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){
 
 @Override
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
  String s = multiSpinnerRent.getSelectedItemsAsString();
  TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sel);
  tv.setText(s);
  
 }
};'

Comment: You can create a callback interface that fires every time an item is clicked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47284385/1140304