# How to create Multiple Selection Spinner in Android

Tags: android, spinner

I am using below code to create a simple Spinner (only single selection is allow)

But now i would like to know how can i use spinner to make multiple selection, I know i can achieve this using Dialog but i have to use Spinner..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Spinner spnr;

    String[] celebrities = {
            "Chris Hemsworth",
            "Jennifer Lawrence",
            "Jessica Alba",
            "Brad Pitt",
            "Tom Cruise",
            "Johnny Depp",
            "Megan Fox",
            "Paul Walker",
            "Vin Diesel"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spnr = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, celebrities);

        spnr.setAdapter(adapter);
        spnr.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {

                        int position = spnr.getSelectedItemPosition();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You have selected "+celebrities[+position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                }
            );
    }

}
```

Comment: What u have tried using Dialog?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i already done with dialog... but i need solution using Spinner

Comment: http://itpeoplealwayswelcome.blogspot.in/2015/06/android-multiple-selection-spinner-item.html

Comment: @Sophie: Why not using ListView?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47284385/1140304

Comment: [MultiSelectSpinner](https://github.com/pratikbutani/MultiSelectSpinner#how-to-use-multiple-item-selection-spinner)

Answer (score 6):

Spinner by default cannot work for Multiple selection.

If you need it, you have to extend it, check here

[Android Spinner with multiple choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015686/android-spinner-with-multiple-choice)

Answer (score 1):

To create a spinner but with MultiSelect dropdown functionality, you can use this library in android
[MultiSelectSpinner](https://github.com/puskal-khadka/MultiSelectSpinner)

You can see readme file to know how to use this library. OR, Here is the simple example showing how to implement this library

- add dependency in app level build.gradle. You can click above library link for current version. For now I'm using 1.0.0

```
    implementation 'com.github.puskal-khadka:MultiSelectSpinner:1.0.0'
```

- Add following view on xml

```xml
<com.puskal.multiselectspinner.MultiSelectSpinnerView
     android:id="@+id/multiSelectSpinner"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
  />
```

- Finally setup data, logic for spinner on activity/fragment

```kotlin
  val testDataList = arrayListOf("Kotlin", "Java", "Python", "Php", "Swift")
        with(binding) {
            multiSelectSpinner.buildCheckedSpinner(testDataList){ selectedPositionList, displayString ->
                tvSelectedPosition.text = "Selected position:  $selectedPositionList" //if kotlin, python selecteed:returned postion will be 0,2
                tvDispString.text = "Display String:  $displayString"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is code support for Android TV leanback D-PAD controller.

```
import android.R
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
import java.util.Arrays
import java.util.LinkedList

/**
 * @author rrallabandi
 */
class MultiSelectionSpinner : AppCompatSpinner, OnMultiChoiceClickListener,
    DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {
    var _items: Array<String>? = null
    var mSelection: BooleanArray? = null
    var simple_adapter: ArrayAdapter<String>

    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context!!) {
        simple_adapter = ArrayAdapter(
            context,
            R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        )
        super.setAdapter(simple_adapter)
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(
        context!!, attrs
    ) {
        simple_adapter = ArrayAdapter(
            context,
            R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        )
        super.setAdapter(simple_adapter)
    }

    override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int, isChecked: Boolean) {
        Log.d("TEST", "onClick " + mSelection!![which] + isChecked)
        if (mSelection != null && which < mSelection!!.size) {
            mSelection!![which] = isChecked
            simple_adapter.clear()
            simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString())
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException(
                "Argument 'which' is out of bounds."
            )
        }
    }

    override fun performClick(): Boolean {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(_items, mSelection, this)
        builder.setOnDismissListener(this)
        builder.show()
        return true
    }

    override fun setAdapter(adapter: SpinnerAdapter) {
        throw RuntimeException(
            "setAdapter is not supported by MultiSelectSpinner."
        )
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param items list of items
     */
    fun setItems(items: Array<String>?) {
        _items = items
        mSelection = BooleanArray(_items!!.size)
        simple_adapter.clear()
        simple_adapter.add(_items!![0])
        Arrays.fill(mSelection, false)
    }

    fun setItems(items: List<String>) {
        _items = items.toTypedArray()
        mSelection = BooleanArray(_items!!.size)
        simple_adapter.clear()
        simple_adapter.add(_items!![0])
        Arrays.fill(mSelection, false)
    }

    fun setSelection(selection: Array<String>) {
        for (cell in selection) {
            for (j in _items!!.indices) {
                if (_items!![j] == cell) {
                    mSelection!![j] = true
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun setSelection(selection: List<String>) {
        for (i in mSelection!!.indices) {
            mSelection!![i] = false
        }
        for (sel in selection) {
            for (j in _items!!.indices) {
                if (_items!![j] == sel) {
                    mSelection!![j] = true
                }
            }
        }
        simple_adapter.clear()
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString())
    }

    override fun setSelection(index: Int) {
        for (i in mSelection!!.indices) {
            mSelection!![i] = false
        }
        if (index >= 0 && index < mSelection!!.size) {
            mSelection!![index] = true
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException(
                "Index " + index
                        + " is out of bounds."
            )
        }
        simple_adapter.clear()
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString())
    }

    fun setSelection(selectedIndicies: IntArray) {
        for (i in mSelection!!.indices) {
            mSelection!![i] = false
        }
        for (index in selectedIndicies) {
            if (index >= 0 && index < mSelection!!.size) {
                mSelection!![index] = true
            } else {
                throw IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Index " + index
                            + " is out of bounds."
                )
            }
        }
        simple_adapter.clear()
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString())
    }

    val selectedStrings: List<String>
        get() {
            val selection: MutableList<String> = LinkedList()
            for (i in _items!!.indices) {
                if (mSelection!![i]) {
                    selection.add(_items!![i])
                }
            }
            return selection
        }
    val selectedIndicies: List<Int>
        get() {
            val selection: MutableList<Int> = LinkedList()
            for (i in _items!!.indices) {
                if (mSelection!![i]) {
                    selection.add(i)
                }
            }
            return selection
        }

    private fun buildSelectedItemString(): String {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        var foundOne = false
        for (i in _items!!.indices) {
            if (mSelection!![i]) {
                if (foundOne) {
                    sb.append(", ")
                }
                foundOne = true
                sb.append(_items!![i])
            }
        }
        return sb.toString()
    }

    val selectedItemsAsString: String
        get() {
            val sb = StringBuilder()
            var foundOne = false
            for (i in _items!!.indices) {
                if (mSelection!![i]) {
                    if (foundOne) {
                        sb.append(", ")
                    }
                    foundOne = true
                    sb.append(_items!![i])
                }
            }
            return sb.toString()
        }

    override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface) {
        Log.d("TEST", "onDismiss" + buildSelectedItemString())
    }
}
```