# Read 3 selected item in the same time

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-spinner

How to read 3 spinner selected item in the same time? I have `spinner1,2,3` in `WorkDetails.java` and their value has been inserted into `SQLite`. In my `UpdatePage.java`, I want to retrieve the selected item out and the selected item should be displayed first in spinner `project1,project2 and project3`.

**UpdatePage.java**

```
public void RetrievePage(String name,String date, String id) {
    final String name2 = name;
    final String date2=date;
    final String id2 = id;
    final EditText name3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    final EditText date3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText12);
    name3.setText(name2);
    date3.setText(date2);

    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    c = database.rawQuery(
        "SELECT i.Weather, i.Status,w.Subcontractors, w.NumberOfPerson,"+
        "w.NumberOfHours, wd.Project, wd.WorkDescription, wd.Per,"+
        "wd.TimeIn, wd.TimeOut FROM Information i LEFT JOIN WorkForce w "+
        "ON w.TInfo_id = i._id "+
        "LEFT JOIN WorkDetails wd ON wd.Twf_id=w._id "+
        "WHERE i.Name = ? AND i._id= ? ",
        new String[]{String.valueOf(name2),String.valueOf(id2)}, null);
    if (c != null) {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Details WD = new Details();
            String Project11 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Project));
            String Project22  =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Project));
            String Project33  =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Project));

            addProject1(Project11);
            addProject2(Project22);
            addProject3(Project33);
            WD.setProject(Project11);
            WD.setProject(Project22);
            WD.setProject(Project33);
        }
    }
    c.close();
}

public void addProject1(String l) {
    project1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner8);
    String[] arr = new String[]{"1","2","3"};
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String project11 = l;
    list.add(project11);
    for (String s : arr) {
        if (!list.contains(s)) {
            list.add(s);
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UpdatePage.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    project1.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void addProject2(String d) {
    project2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner9);
    String[] arr = new String[]{"1","2","3"};
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String project22 = d;
    list.add(project22);
    for (String s:arr) {
        if(!list.contains(s)) {
            list.add(s);
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UpdatePage.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    project2.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void addProject3(String e) {
    project3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner13);
    String[] arr = new String[]{"1","2","3"};
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String project33 = e;
    list.add(project33);
    for (String s:arr) {
        if (!list.contains(s)) {
            list.add(s);
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UpdatePage.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    project3.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Assume `spinner1` holds value 1, `spinner2` holds 2 and `spinner3` holds 3. When come to `updatePage`, spinner `project1` should display 1 first, `project2` display 2 and so on. But the problem now is project1,2,and 3 display value 1 first...how can I achieve this?

Comment: hi, Let me clarify something here first,
so what you exactly want is that when you change the value of spinner  the 1st value shows into 1st spinner, 2nd value shows into 2nd spinner and 3rd value shows into 3rd spinner.
is that right?

Comment: I sugessted you using this [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523715/multi-selection-spinner-in-android-without-alertdialog)

Comment: @HardikChauhan Exactly..:)

Comment: @John : and are you using the same array for assign value in all three spinner?

Comment: @hardik did you mean the name?

Comment: @John : i mean that which value you want to show and get from the spinner? which array of list or something?

Comment: @HardikChauhan It depends on what value was inserted into SQLite. If spinner 1 was inserted value 1, then in project1 should display value 1 first..

Comment: so if the value is same for all spinner you can set same.

Comment: @HardikChauhan the item in the list are same but the item selected might not the same

Comment: Yes so if the list is same, so when you select on value from array get the index of that value and set the same for other spinner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94053/discussion-between-hardik-chauhan-and-john).

Comment: Hi John, let's try to decide your problem. Go to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95922/discussion-between-john-and-walkmn) for clarify what you need. How your program are working at this moment?

Comment: Did you get a resolution for this?

Comment: @ManuSunny ya, I already got it. The spinner display the same item is because of this  `String Project11 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Project));
            String Project22  =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Project));
            String Project33  =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Project));`. I should add `c.moveToNext()` between them

Answer (score 4):

You can try a little bit of logic for this purpose

Take three values from the database. Let them be

`selected_value_of_spinner1`,`selected_value_of_spinner2`,`selected_value_of__spinner3`

Then define your method `getPosition` as below

```
public int getPosition(Spinner your_spinner, String string_value){

    int position = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<your_spinner.getCount();i++){
        if (your_spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).equals(string_value)){
            position = i;
        }
    }
    return position;
    }
```

The show the values got from the database in your spinners like following

```
your_spinner1.setSelection(getPosition(your_spinner1, selected_value_of_spinner1));
your_spinner2.setSelection(getPosition(your_spinner2, selected_value_of_spinner2));
your_spinner3.setSelection(getPosition(your_spinner3, selected_value_of_spinner3));
```

Basically what happens here is

1. You get the value from the database
2. You match the value got from database in your spinner to get its position in spinner by `getPosition()` method.
3. Set the spinner value according to the position you get from step 2 by `setSelection(position)` method.

Comment: I have 3 spinner, which spinnner should I write for the (your_spinner)

Comment: Do it three times for 3 spinners @John

Comment: how abou the string_value?

Comment: I have edited the answer for your better understanding. try now. @John

Comment: I still can't get it..what value  should I put in selected_value_of_spinner

Comment: in your `updatepage.java` you get the values stored from the database right? and those values are selected values for the spinners right? so just pass those three selected values to the function. @John

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92922/discussion-between-john-and-zahan-safallwa).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are having 3 `Spinner` items then you can do this:

```
project1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectedItem1 = list.get(position).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

project2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectedItem2 = list.get(position).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

project3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectedItem3 = list.get(position).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

and declare the:

```
String selectedItem1;
String selectedTtem2;
String selectedItem3;
```

as global variables. Hope it helps!!!

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. I already got the answer . The spinner display the same item is because of this `String Project11 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Project)); String Project22 =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Project)); String Project33 =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Project));`. I should add c.moveToNext() between them