# Multi selection in spinner

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-spinner

I created a 2 spinners and I need to enable users to select multiple things from each of them. I manage to add checkbox via android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice. Now i manage to get everything that I wanted but problem is how can I enable user to select multiple things there are already check boxes but when user click on some item it immediately close spinner and stay selected on that item.

This is the design that I get and that I want but problem is with selection.

http://pokit.org/get/?1c872c5becdeb79b792617fc870f1da4.jpg
This is selection:
http://pokit.org/get/?e892ee2f941ab3f98b8ee51e6f9e8fc6.jpg

This is my current code for that spinner:

```
 public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Spinner placesspinner=(Spinner)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner_locations);
    Spinner catspinner=(Spinner)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner_category);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,places);
    placesspinner.setAdapter(adp1);
    catspinner.setAdapter(adp1);
    // Setup any handles to view objects here
    // EditText etFoo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etFoo);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47284385/1140304

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Spinner control is in Single Choice selection mode.

What you done is you just changed the Layout to show the spinner item with Checkbox. which doesn't mean you are showing an muti selection spinner control.

You can refer any below mentioned sample to implement multi select spinner.

[multi-select-drop-down-list](https://asnehal.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/multi-select-drop-down-list-in-android/)

[android-spinner-like-ui-for-selecting-multiple-options](http://android-spinner-like-ui-for-selecting-multiple-options)

[spinner-with-multiple-selectiondescription here](http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/09/spinner-with-multiple-selection-in.html)