# how to select the multiple values in a spinner by checking the checkbox. And i need to fetch the selected item from the spinner?

Tags: android

I want to select multiple values in a spinner by checking the checkbox and I need to fetch the selected items from the spinner.

Comment: try these links and post the error if you faced any issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523715/multi-selection-spinner-in-android-without-alertdialog http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015686/android-spinner-with-multiple-choice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Spinner with multiple choice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015686/android-spinner-with-multiple-choice)

Comment: Now i can select the multiple values from the spinner ,the problem with the how to set the data which is  selected before and when i select the data from the spinner ,i want to get the selected item from spinner and split  the data from comma(,) and i want to store it in a string.

Comment: Can anyone suggest me please,i struck here i cannot move on to next step.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way here is prefect example

https://asnehal.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/