# how to select multiple items in a spinner?

Tags: android, mysql, listview

how to select multiple items in a spinner ,and the items are loading from the MYsql database and when ever we select the items it as to store the id to the database

Comment: I don't think that spinner is designed to select multiple items

Comment: Have you searched before posting the question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015686/android-spinner-with-multiple-choice

Comment: need to table update code oncheckedchangelistener.my opinion to add code snap so its more easy to help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47284385/1140304

Comment: [MultiSelectSpinner](https://github.com/pratikbutani/MultiSelectSpinner#how-to-use-multiple-item-selection-spinner)

Answer (score 0):

Spinner by default, won't allow multiselect. You have to extend it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015686/android-spinner-with-multiple-choice)