# I want to create a multiselect spinner in android. How can i do it ?

Tags: android, android-studio

Steps which i want to be followed are 
1) Click on the Spinner.
2) On Clicking Spinner a Dialog Box Should Appear having multiselect ListView or something Equivalent **without having checkboxes or radio button** ,Selection Should be highlighted with different background.
3) On Clicking positive button , **value should be displayed in the spinner** separated by " , ".

Comment: this answer may help to you; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523715/multi-selection-spinner-in-android-without-alertdialog?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: already gone through that library does fulfill the desired needs , please read question thoroghly

Comment: @MohammedFarhan I would really like to know how you got that library to work because there are virtually no instructions on usage syntax.

Comment: @IRGeekSauce, hi sorry for that link, it was commented previous year and i don't know what made me to do so. It doesn't full fill the OP needs. Ill just remove the comment.