# If i select an item in a spinner it should not be selected again and if i delete an item it should appear again in the list of spinner items

Tags: android, xml, spinner

[image: when i click spinner]
[image: after i selected items in spinner]

In spinner, whenever I selected an item it should be inactive or stop user from selecting again and whenever the user deletes the selected item that item should be active and user can select again. Items in the list should be added and deleted dynamically. Can anyone tell me how to do this?
Any help will be appreciated. If you can't understand the question please comment here

my code for adding new item and removing that item given below:

```
  public void add_click()
{
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            spin = findViewById(R.id.spinnerLayout);
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View addview = (layoutInflater).inflate(R.layout.spinner, null);
            addview.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup
                    .LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            game_name_Spinner = addview.findViewById(R.id.gamename);
            player_level_Spinner = addview.findViewById(R.id.level);
            remove = addview.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
            s_game = name1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            s_level = level1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            game_name_Spinner.setText(s_game);
            player_level_Spinner.setText(s_level);



            remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    String last_removed;
                    ((LinearLayout) addview.getParent()).removeView(addview);
                    gamename.addAll(removed_item);
                    adap1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PlayerProfile.this, android.R.layout
                            .simple_spinner_dropdown_item, gamename);
                    name1.setAdapter(adap1);
                    adap1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            if (name1.getSelectedItemPosition()>0)
            {
                int count = removed_item.size();
                for (int i = 0; i<=count; i++)
                {
                    game_name_Spinner.setId(i);
                }
                idl = game_name_Spinner.getId();
                game_removed = name1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                removed_item.add(game_removed);
                LinkedHashSet<String> hashSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
                hashSet.add(game_removed);
                removed_item.clear();
                removed_item.add(game_removed);

                adap1.remove(name1.getSelectedItem().toString());

            }
            container = findViewById(R.id.container);
            container.addView(addview);
            name1.setSelection(0);
            level1.setSelection(0);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi selection spinner in android without AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523715/multi-selection-spinner-in-android-without-alertdialog)

Comment: @ZaidMirza code added

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH I don't think it is duplicate, I need to add and delete items dynamically