# Multiple select drop down in android

Tags: android, listview, multi-select, android-library

I am now working on an android app where i required to load all country list on a dropdown. My User Requirement to add multiselect dropdown like as following which we use in web using JQuery....

[image: Multiselect Dropdown]

I am searching this type of dropdown but not get any solution yet. How can i solve this requirement? any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**N.B: I found following type of drop down which not accepted to my user.**

[image]

Comment: you need that search option too ?

Comment: you can do 1 one thing load all country list in recylerview and select from that

Comment: when user selects 1 country, empty your autocompletetextview and show selected value as tab, this way, when user types again, drop down will be shown

Comment: check [here](https://github.com/hootsuite/nachos). for add mutiple textview.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24523964/5909412)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are talking about is **Chips View**, there are multiples third party lib which can help you

https://github.com/hootsuite/nachos

https://github.com/pchmn/MaterialChipsInput

You can get help from this.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a spinner in your own xml and create a custom adapter for that spinner.

These links may help you:

[Multi Select Spinner with Search/Filter](https://jitpack.io/p/laurachelaru/MultiSelectSpinner)

[How to develop Multi Select spinner](https://trinitytuts.com/tips/multiselect-spinner-item-in-android/)

[Multi Select Spinner](https://github.com/prsidhu/MultiSelectSpinner)

[Multi Select Spinner with Search/Filter](https://github.com/pratikbutani/MultiSelectSpinner)

[Multi selection spinner in android without AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523715/multi-selection-spinner-in-android-without-alertdialog)