# multiple select spinner with retrieve data key and value

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

how to create multiple select spinner, and **retrieve data(key and value)** from spinner.

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
```

Comment: Did you look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523715/multi-selection-spinner-in-android-without-alertdialog

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi selection spinner in android without AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523715/multi-selection-spinner-in-android-without-alertdialog)