# setting multiple values to spinner in Android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I can populate more than 1 `spinner` in Android with multiple values. I want to **display more than 1 value in spinner i.e In "0" position** (spinner index) I want to set more than one  value   as per the user dynamically. When user select the first value that will set in 0 position and when user click the second value it will added to same 0 position without replacing it. So that two values can be visible  and can be use.

**Is it possible in android spinner? If yes any suggestion please ..**

Comment: Yes, possible. the term you are looking is `spinner with multiple selection`. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015686/android-spinner-with-multiple-choice and a tutorial from http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/09/spinner-with-multiple-selection-in.html

Comment: thank you i will check and let you know :)

Comment: still you are struggling?

Comment: @ling.s thank you a lot for your concern .Now i can select multi string in android but till now i am struggling how can i use arraylist in Multispinner Class so that i can select multiple  name with their  id for a particular spinner .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the

http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/android-multi-selection-dialogs/ 
or  http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/09/spinner-with-multiple-selection-in.html. Let me know if any error??
check this,  I think this is what you looking for 
http://codethis.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/a-spinner-control-for-android-with-multi-select-support/

In MultiSelectionSpinner Class

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;

public class MultiSelectionSpinner extends Spinner implements  OnMultiChoiceClickListener {  
    String[] _items = null;  

    boolean[] mSelection = null;  

    ArrayAdapter<String> simple_adapter;  

    public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context) {  
        super(context);  

        simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,  
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);  
        super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);  
    }  

    public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {  
        super(context, attrs);  

        simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,  
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);  
        super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);  
    }  

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {  
        if (mSelection != null && which < mSelection.length) {  
            mSelection[which] = isChecked;  

            simple_adapter.clear();  
            simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());  
        } else {  
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(  
            "Argument 'which' is out of bounds.");  
        }  
    }  

    @Override  
    public boolean performClick() {  
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());  
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(_items, mSelection, this);  
        builder.show();  
        return true;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter adapter) {  
        throw new RuntimeException(  
        "setAdapter is not supported by MultiSelectSpinner.");  
    }  

    public void setItems(String[] items) {  
        _items = items;  
        mSelection = new boolean[_items.length];  
        simple_adapter.clear();  
        simple_adapter.add(_items[0]);  
        Arrays.fill(mSelection, false);  
    }  

    public void setItems(List<String> items) {  
        _items = items.toArray(new String[items.size()]);  
        mSelection = new boolean[_items.length];  
        simple_adapter.clear();  
        simple_adapter.add(_items[0]);  
        Arrays.fill(mSelection, false);  
    }  

    public void setSelection(String[] selection) {  
        for (String cell : selection) {  
            for (int j = 0; j < _items.length; ++j) {  
                if (_items[j].equals(cell)) {  
                    mSelection[j] = true;  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  

    public void setSelection(List<String> selection) {  
        for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {  
            mSelection[i] = false;  
        }  
        for (String sel : selection) {  
            for (int j = 0; j < _items.length; ++j) {  
                if (_items[j].equals(sel)) {  
                    mSelection[j] = true;  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        simple_adapter.clear();  
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());  
    }  

    public void setSelection(int index) {  
        for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {  
            mSelection[i] = false;  
        }  
        if (index >= 0 && index < mSelection.length) {  
            mSelection[index] = true;  
        } else {  
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + index  
                    + " is out of bounds.");  
        }  
        simple_adapter.clear();  
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());  
    }  

    public void setSelection(int[] selectedIndicies) {  
        for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {  
            mSelection[i] = false;  
        }  
        for (int index : selectedIndicies) {  
            if (index >= 0 && index < mSelection.length) {  
                mSelection[index] = true;  
            } else {  
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + index  
                        + " is out of bounds.");  
            }     
        }  
        simple_adapter.clear();  
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());  
    }  

    public List<String> getSelectedStrings() {  
        List<String> selection = new LinkedList<String>();  
        for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {  
            if (mSelection[i]) {  
                selection.add(_items[i]);  
            }  
        }  
        return selection;  
    }  

    public List<Integer> getSelectedIndicies() {  
        List<Integer> selection = new LinkedList<Integer>();  
        for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {  
            if (mSelection[i]) {  
                selection.add(i);  
            }  
        }  
        return selection;  
    }  

    private String buildSelectedItemString() {  
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
        boolean foundOne = false;  

        for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {  
            if (mSelection[i]) {  
                if (foundOne) {  
                    sb.append(", ");  
                }  
                foundOne = true;  

                sb.append(_items[i]);  
            }  
        }  
        return sb.toString();  
    }  

    public String getSelectedItemsAsString() {  
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
        boolean foundOne = false;  

        for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {  
            if (mSelection[i]) {  
                if (foundOne) {  
                    sb.append(", ");  
                }  
                foundOne = true;  
                sb.append(_items[i]);  
            }  
        }  
        return sb.toString();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: this is not actually an answer to the question

Comment: @ling.s  I am new to android and getting lots of confusion .So can you  give some example code how to set multiple values to spinner by separate the value with "," or few  explanation???

Comment: http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/09/spinner-with-multiple-selection-in.html follow this link. It helps me :)

Comment: Any Idea for "multiSpinner" with  arrylist or with adapter ??

Comment: String[] _items is define here.. Its Fine. I want To define ArrayList here.. Any Idea Please Help.. ??

Answer (score 1):

Blow is the solution :-

```
   package com.kazi.createActivity;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.kazi.R;

import java.util.List;


public class MultiSpinner  extends Spinner implements
        OnMultiChoiceClickListener, DialogInterface.OnCancelListener {

    private List<String> items;
    private boolean[] selected;
    private String defaultText;
    private MultiSpinnerListener listener;

    public MultiSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MultiSpinner(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public MultiSpinner(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked)
            selected[which] = true;
        else
            selected[which] = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // refresh text on spinner
        StringBuffer spinnerBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        boolean someUnselected = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            if (selected[i] == true) {
                spinnerBuffer.append(items.get(i));
                spinnerBuffer.append(", ");
            } else {
                someUnselected = true;
            }
        }
        String spinnerText;
        if (someUnselected) {
            spinnerText = spinnerBuffer.toString();
            if (spinnerText.length() > 2)
                spinnerText = spinnerText.substring(0, spinnerText.length() - 2);
        } else {
            spinnerText = defaultText;
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
              R.layout.spinner_list_item,
                new String[] { spinnerText });
        setAdapter(adapter);
        listener.onItemsSelected(selected);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(
                items.toArray(new CharSequence[items.size()]), selected, this);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        builder.setOnCancelListener(this);
        builder.show();
        return true;
    }

    public void setItems(List<String> items, String[] allText,
                         MultiSpinnerListener listener) {
        this.items = items;

        this.listener = listener;

        // all selected by default
        selected = new boolean[items.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < selected.length; i++)
            selected[i] = false;

        // all text on the spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                R.layout.spinner_list_item, allText );
        setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public interface MultiSpinnerListener {
        public void onItemsSelected(boolean[] selected);
    }
}
```

I created this xml layout:-

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/spiner_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/spiner_height"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:text="Medium Text"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```