# Get the alert dialog selected value to edittext

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am following this tutorial http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/android-multi-selection-dialogs/ and I want to get selected value of alert dialog to my edittext can any one help me with that, I need to get details in edittext

```
    public class PagesFragment extends Fragment{

/*private PopupWindow pw;
private boolean expanded;       //to  store information whether the selected values are displayed completely or in shortened representatn
public static boolean[] checkSelected;*/

private Spinner spfrom;
private Spinner spto;
private Spinner spheightfrom;
private Spinner spheightto;
private Spinner splang;
private Spinner sprelg;
private Spinner spmrgstatus;
private Spinner spcountry;
private Spinner spstate;
private Spinner spcity;
private EditText tv;
private ImageView btnmother;
private ImageView btnrelgn;
protected CharSequence[] _options = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};
protected boolean[] _selections = new boolean[_options.length];

protected Button _optionsButton;
protected EditText inputTemp;
private EditText lang;
private ImageButton btnlangs;
static Dialog d ;


public PagesFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //String strtext = getArguments().getString("position");
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_profile, container, false);

    lang = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtmothertongue);
     btnlangs = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnmothertongue);
    spfrom=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinneragefrom);
    spto=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerageto);
    spheightfrom=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerhfrom);
    spheightto=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerhto);
    //splang=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerlang);
    //sprelg=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerrel);
    spmrgstatus=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnermrgstatus);
    spcountry=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnercountry);
    spstate=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerstate);
    spcity=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnercity);

    btnlangs.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDialog(0);

        }
    });
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        return
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Planets")
                        .setMultiChoiceItems(_options, _selections, new DialogSelectionClickHandler())
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogButtonClickHandler())
                        .create();
    }

    public class DialogSelectionClickHandler implements DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked, boolean selected) {
            Log.i("ME", _options[clicked] + " selected: " + selected);
        }
    }


    public class DialogButtonClickHandler implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked) {
            switch (clicked) {
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    inputTemp.setText("");
                    for (int i = 0; i < _options.length; i++) {
                        if(_selections[i]){
                            if(inputTemp.getText().toString().length()>0){
                                inputTemp.setText(inputTemp.getText().toString().trim()+","+_options[i]);
                            }else{
                                inputTemp.setText(_options[i]);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void printSelectedPlanets(){
        for( int i = 0; i < _options.length; i++ ){
            Log.i( "ME", _options[ i ] + " selected: " + _selections[i] );
        }
    }
 // on click of button display the dialog


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
            R.array.height_from, R.layout.my_spinner);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    spheightfrom.setAdapter(adapter1);


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
            R.array.height_to, R.layout.my_spinner);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    spheightto.setAdapter(adapter2);


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
            R.array.age_from, R.layout.my_spinner);
    adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    spfrom.setAdapter(adapter3);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter10 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
            R.array.age_to, R.layout.my_spinner);
    adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    spto.setAdapter(adapter10);


    btnrelgn=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnrelgn);

    btnrelgn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),ReligionList.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });




    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter5 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
            R.array.mrgstatus, R.layout.my_spinner);
    adapter5.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    spmrgstatus.setAdapter(adapter5);


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter6=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(). getBaseContext(), R.array.country,R.layout.my_spinner);
    adapter6.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    spcountry.setAdapter(adapter6);


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter7=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(). getBaseContext(), R.array.state,R.layout.my_spinner);
    adapter7.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    spstate.setAdapter(adapter7);


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter8=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(). getBaseContext(), R.array.city,R.layout.my_spinner);
    adapter8.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    spcity.setAdapter(adapter8);
    return rootView;

}

}
```

Comment: declare `EditText inputTemp` and `String a`  globally.

Comment: nope its not working

Comment: r u getting any error o wat?

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: `nope its not working`. That does not bring you/us further. You are supposed to show the used code and tell the errors you got at compile time or run time. Now you let us guess. Please first tell where you need help.

Comment: my question is i want to get alertdailog checked items in my edittext.read question carefully

Comment: I see no question. And you are not telling WHEN/WHERE you want to get them. Do we have to guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to initialize EditText in onCreate() and set or change value at positive button clicked :

**Example :**

```
    protected CharSequence[] _options = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};
    protected boolean[] _selections = new boolean[_options.length];

    protected Button _optionsButton;
    protected EditText inputTemp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        inputTemp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittexts);
        _optionsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        _optionsButton.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());
    }

    public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showDialog(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        return
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Planets")
                        .setMultiChoiceItems(_options, _selections, new DialogSelectionClickHandler())
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogButtonClickHandler())
                        .create();
    }

    public class DialogSelectionClickHandler implements DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked, boolean selected) {
            Log.i("ME", _options[clicked] + " selected: " + selected);
        }
    }


    public class DialogButtonClickHandler implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked) {
            switch (clicked) {
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    inputTemp.setText("");
                    for (int i = 0; i < _options.length; i++) {
                        if(_selections[i]){
                            if(inputTemp.getText().toString().length()>0){
                                inputTemp.setText(inputTemp.getText().toString().trim()+","+_options[i]);
                            }else{
                                inputTemp.setText(_options[i]);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i already upvote it and in you code EditText initialization and set dialog selected value code is wrong.

Comment: Bro it works fine with activity but not with Fragment