# How to make a multispinner where data coming from webservice

Tags: android

I want to make a `multispinner` where data comes through `webservice`.currently i am having a simple `spinner` where i am getting single item at a time from `webservice`.Is there anyone who can help me in this?

Comment: make a custom pop-up with checked list view. In every list-item, put one text and one checkbox.

Comment: use this link i hope it will work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015686/android-spinner-with-multiple-choice

Comment: Yogendra sir i am using the same code as given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015686/android-spinner-with-multiple-choice.But problem is setAdapter is not supported by multiselectspinner how to solve this issue?

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me?