# setAdapter gridview send context

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have this piece of code (LINE 2) that is returning :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.projecti_popularmovies/com.example.android.projecti_popularmovies.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My code is :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public MovieFragment mMovieFragment;
public Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContext = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mMovieFragment = new MovieFragment();
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, mMovieFragment)
                .commit();
    }
    if(mMovieFragment.getArrayImages() == null){
        Log.v(null, "Array is empty");
    }
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, mMovieFragment.getArrayImages()));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I have checked the getArrayImages before this and its not null, I also tried to send the activity by getActivity() and it cannot find the method getActivity().

**the word *this* refers to this activity context**

Here is my constructor for ImageAdapter class:

```
public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] images) {
```

This is the code to populate the mArrayImages:

```
    private Void getMovieImagesFromJson(String movieJSONstr) throws JSONException {

        final String OWM_RESULTS = "results";
        final String OWM_POSTERPATH = "poster_path";

        JSONObject movieJson = new JSONObject(movieJSONstr);
        JSONArray movieArray = movieJson.getJSONArray(OWM_RESULTS);

        Log.v("SIZE MOVIE ARRAY: ", Integer.toString(movieArray.length()));

        for(int i = 0; i < movieArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject movieObj = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);
            mArrayImages[i] = movieObj.getString(OWM_POSTERPATH);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `MainActivity.this` instead of this?

Comment: Can you post the whole Activity class to show where exactly is your GridView code in Activity?

Comment: Added the onCreate method, everything else is not relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a GlobalVariable

```
public Context mContext;
```

In your `OnCreate()` do this :

```
mContext = this;
```

Then you can call setAdapter and your `Context` won't be null.

```
gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(mContext, mMovieFragment.getArrayImages()));
```

### EDIT

Try to use `MainActivity.this` instead.

Comment: didn't fix my problem

Comment: Create a question and link me the link and I'll try to help you :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724689/android-multichoice-spinner-with-searchview-functionality

Comment: what do you need to see more? If the activity was not created it woudnt show anything on screen

Comment: @JoaoPereira You have to use `YoiurActivity.this`

Comment: Can you post the `getArrayImages()`?

Comment: So your code in your `onCreate` is what you have posted?

Comment: I added the method to populate ArrayImages

Comment: mContext = this; goes under the setcontentview

Comment: And your get method returns a string not a String[]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
MainActivity.this
```

use `getApplicationContext()`