# getting error while using multispinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to select multiple items in spinner but getting runtime exception due to java.lang.CastException in XML file

XML:

```
<com.example.lenovo.abc.MultiSpinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/hobby"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.91"
/>
```

MultiSpinner class:

[Android Spinner with multiple choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015686/android-spinner-with-multiple-choice)

About class

```
package com.example.lenovo.abc;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class About extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);
        TextView intro= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.introducing);
        MultiSpinner hobby= (MultiSpinner) findViewById(R.id.hobby);
        List<String> h = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hobby));
        hobby.setItems(h,"Hobbies", (MultiSpinner.MultiSpinnerListener) this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hobby.setItems(h,"Hobbies", (MultiSpinner.MultiSpinnerListener) this);
```

You are not implementing MultiSpinner.MultiSpinnerListener in this activity and passing context casting to MultiSpinner.MultiSpinnerListener. Try implementing the listener in this activity.

Comment: if the issue is not solved , please add the exception trace.